# How to make TabLayout in Arc shape?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to achieve to make the tabLayout in arc shape

[image: In the given Image]

I tried many ways but did not make like that. How can I make my tabLayout like in the image?

Comment: how can I achieve this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you show likely still contains a rectangular tab layout but it renders such that humans perceive it as being arc shaped.

Play around with the look and feel of the tab layout. Mainly make the component see-through (maybe the keyword is opacity), ensure you have the right background and then only focus on the rendering of the tabs, which either means to draw splines making the arc or again having a suitable background.